# VSTS Release - 'runtime' replacement of Environment Variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have made a release in vsts with some environment variables.

One of those environment variables is as follows:

```
#Array
[ { "name":"password", "value":"thisismypassword" }, { ... } ]
```

However, I get an output parameter from one of the release tasks which returns the password. So I thought to make a 'tag' and replace it when the output parameter has returned:

```
[ { "name":"password", "value":"<Password>" } ]
```

When my output parameter has returned I can create an powershell task to replace the  'tag' with the real password. However to replace, it should be either an string or an valid powershell array. If I directly use the environment variable, it breaks on the first ':' with an error message (because it is not a legit powershell command/format);

```
#This breaks    
$var = $(environment_variable)
```

Hence I thought to convert it to a String, replace it, Convert it back to json object and set it back on the environment variable:

```
$Setting = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject '$(environment_variable)'
$Setting = $Setting -replace "<Password>", "$(Output_Password)"

#Tried both below
$Setting_JSON - ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Setting
$Setting_JNSON = [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert]::SerializeObject($Setting, [Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting]::None)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$(environment_variable)]$Setting_JSON"
```

However these produce a json string which is of a different format and the step which uses this variable does not understand;

```
#Output
["@{name=Password;value=thisisapasswordvalue}"]

#Expected (and needed) Output
[ { "name":"password", "value":"thisisapasswordvalue" } ]
```

Comment: When do you want the environment variable `password` show as tag and when do you want to show the variable with it's real value? Can't you use logging command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell#set-in-script) to change the value of the variable `password` between `thisismypassword` and `<Password>`?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I am talking about a Release Pipeline and I do not fully understand what you mean with use the logging command.

Comment: Do you want to achieve showing `password` variable with the value `thisismypassword` when executing a task and showing the value as `<Password>` when executing another task?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT No, I get the real password from an output of another task. The tag <Password> should be replaced with the password of the output when available after the task.

Comment: So after the task showing the real password, you can add a powershell task with `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=password]<Password>"` to change the value, then the following task will show the variable with the value `<Password>`.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT No, Because my environment variable is an array of settings of which 1 is the <password> which needs to be replaced

Comment: Can you add the screen shot of the environment variable you set in release definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#This breaks    
$var = $(environment_variable)
```

For this, you can use this:

```
$var = $Env:variablename
```

This works at my side:

```
$Setting = $env:Var1
$Setting = $Setting -replace "<Password>", "NewValue"
```